# Why do I have new and strange networks (_not wifi_) in my network manager? 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, network-manager, security

Ok, so I updated my system to 14.04 last week (running on a Dell XPS13 ultrabook- but I'm not a developer, not particularly technically minded). Some strange things happened with network manager.

First, it stopped communicating with my 3G modem (Sierra Aircard 312U). Around $100 later I have a 3G router broadcasting a wireless signal that I can hook up to (although Ubuntu lost the signal overnight and I had to restart the computer to get it communicating again).

This has been deeply frustrating and unwelcome. But its not the weird bit.

I have two unknown networks listed in the Network Manager's dropdown box. The first is for a "Galaxy Note3 Network". The second is for "Tsai's iPhone Network". Wifi networks, (including my phone's hotspot) and all the usual stuff is listed below these two.

(If I tether my phone to the computer to access the internet (i.e. hook up a cable), the list says "wired connection 1", then Tsai's and Galaxy Note3 would appear next, with wifi options in a section below that).

I cannot edit connections for either of these new networks, or gather any settings info at all - or even delete them. They are persistent across restarts.

Any ideas? Anyone else? Have I somehow been hacked by a clumsy infiltrator? I downloaded the update from the Australian mirror.

**EDIT**

Picture of the menu

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Answering the question

One of the people in the area around you is *hosting a hotspot* using their **iPhone**, and another person is broadcasting a hotspot using their **Samsung Galaxy Note 3**. You shouldn't be worried about the networks that you are *unfamiliar with*, because people *make their own* networks for different purposes.

### Hacking

It is very unlikely that a *mobile or tablet* would be used for hacking, because the hardware on most portable devices is simply *not powerful enough* to make the hacker's time worthwhile.

### About being not able to edit the networks

You won't be able to edit them because if you haven't connected to them with a password, the network details are not able to be given to your computer. However the names of those networks will still be there. This is so Network Manager has an idea of how to connect to the network next time the user requests to connect to the remembered network.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but that's not it. These aren't wifi hotspots. I phrased the question incorrectly, sorry. I've edited it for clarity.

Comment: I am also seeing the problem and can confirm that the networks are following me around wherever I go. They are not available hotspots.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but the only thing I have found while trying to solve a similar issue on my 14.04.2 install. I had a similar menu entry that mysteriously appeared and eventually realised it had appeared after I had paired my phone to my laptop via bluetooth (it would appear whether bluetooth was switched on or not). In my case this seemed to be causing Wifi connection problems too so was not just a cosmetic issue.

So for the benefit of anyone googling for an answer to this: Simply delete the relevant paired device in Bluetooth Settings.

It would probably be useful if it was indicated that these menu entries are for bluetooth tethering or some such as it really isn't clear what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a bluetooth connection, which you can get more information on with nmcli:

```
nmcli -p con
```